# How to know charge of a particle from position and momentum?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, charge

It was mentioned in one documentary that the only think we need to know about a particle is it's position and momentum, so we can calculate every other quantity from this. If it is correct how do we measure charge from $x$ and $p$?

Comment: You cannot calculate charge from position and momentum because it is independent from them and so are a lot of other quantities.

Comment: Maybe one could make an argument that judging by the (uncertain) measured position and momentum of a particle under certain conditions (like in an electric field) at various times, one could deduce its charge. Of course these details would be important in that argument.

Comment: can you give a link for the documentary?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the context of the question. But I would guess you're talking about particle physics. In that case: This is a semi-common belief which is for example written in chapter 4.1 of Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics (paraphrased):

> The independent variables $x$ and $p$ of classical mechanics are represented by Hermitian operators $X$ and $P$. Classically, every dynamical variable is a function $\omega(x,p)$, and the operators corresponding to dependent variables $\omega(x,p)$ are given by Hermitian operators $\Omega(X,P)$

The origin of this claim (I think) is that in classical mechanics, the initial position and momentum (or velocity) of a particle fully determine its future motion. From measurements of its motion, given the initial position and momentum, one can infer its charge, or mass, or other physical variables. A particle of charge $2q$ moves differently than one of charge $q$.

However I have to warn you that, despite my utmost respect for this very clear textbook, there are limitations to this principle which are not mentioned in this section of the book (or maybe at all). In particular, trying to form a particle's arrival time operator out of the classical formulas for $t$, like $t=x/v=mx/p$ for a free particle, do not lead to expected results in the quantum case. This is an active area of study and has been for decades.

Comment: Also I should warn you that physics documentaries allow themselves to be really "loose" with their talk and a lot of things claimed aren't known in a _scientific_ way, they are rather grandiose interpretations of existing theory which might not be as true as they are presented. Drama is exciting... actual physics is also extremely exciting, but far more intricate than possible to explain in a 2 hour documentary to those who have little mathematical background.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is if it's in an electromagnetic field you could determine it's acceleration as a function of charge? Pretty sure a charged an un-charged particle would be indistinguishable from just their position and momentum values alone without external information though.

Comment: Mass is in fact a type of charge and momentum does in fact depend on mass... Outside of this, I cannot think of any other case.

Comment: @GarethMeredith  In what way is mass a type of charge?

Comment: Charge and mass appear to be fundamentally related. Readjusting the definition of charge, the mass charge is Gm^2.

Comment: You could argue there is one exception, the neutrino, but even then, its mass charge is extremely small, so equally it would possess a very small charge, so small that detecting it would not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Either the documentary was wrong, or you may have misremembered or misunderstood what it actually said. In classical physics, two particles with different charge can have the same position and momentum. And quantum mechanics says that we *can’t* know both the exact position and the exact momentum.

Answer (score -1):

I'll put this in as a possible answer, mass is a type of charge... And has been alluded to for a number of years. The only correction required to a mass square quantity is the Newtonian constant. Mass square quantities are very important especially in the heirarchy problem, such as Regge Trajectories.

Comment: New evidence has supported my notion I held onto for years, now there is evidence of a charge dipole associated to the neutrino. This gives great credence to the notion that mass and charge are synonymous.